# 16 задание ЕГЭ по информатике

Tags: python, циклы

Помогите решить задание. Мой код выдаёт не тот ответ. Правильный ответ: 384

```
def f(n):
    if n > 20:
        return n*n*n
    elif n <= 20 and n % 2 == 0:
        return 3*f(n-1) + f(n+3)
    elif n <= 20 and n % 2 != 0:
        return f(n+2) + 2*f(n+3)

c = 0
for i in range(1, 1001):
    k = str(f(i))
    zero = 0
    for i in k:
        if i == '1':
            zero += 1
        if zero < 1:
            c += 1
print(c)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: при n > 20 должно быть n * n * n ***+*** n, а вы делаете return n * n * n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def f(n):
    if n > 20:             
        return n*n*n + n            # опечатка 1: не хватает +n 
    elif n % 2 == 0:                # условия можно упростить
        return 3 * f(n+1) + f(n+3)  # опечатка 2: +1, а не -1
    else:
        return f(n+2) + 2 * f(n+3)

count = 0
for i in range(1, 1001):
    k = str(f(i))
    if '1' not in k:                # проверка на отсутствие 1 в числе
        count += 1                  # можно обойтись без цикла for i in k

print(count)
```

выведет 384

Answer (score 2):

Подправил код, теперь работает правильно. Пояснения в коде

```
def f(n):
    if n > 20:
        return n*n*n+n # тут +n забыли
    elif n <= 20 and n % 2 == 0:
        return 3*f(n+1) + f(n+3) # здесь должно быть не n-1, а n+1
    elif n <= 20 and n % 2 != 0:
        return f(n+2) + 2*f(n+3)

c = 0
for i in range(1, 1001):
    k = str(f(i))
    zero = 0
    for i in k:
        if i == '1':
            zero += 1
    if zero < 1: # Надо вывести количество чисел, а не цифр
        c += 1
print(c)
```